# How does an RMI respond when tuned to a VOT station?

Tags: rmi

I know that a VOT station for testing VORs broadcasts a 360 radial signal, so on a VOR, the indication would be 360 with a 'FROM' or 180 with a 'TO' indication, but how does an RMI respond if tuned to a VOT station?

Would the RMI simply home to the station because it points to the *direction signal is coming from*, or would it point at the 180 position because it detects that it is on a 360 radial 'FROM' the station?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will point at the 180 position

[VOR Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range)

> A VOT differs from a VOR in that it replaces the variable directional signal with another omnidirectional signal, in a sense transmitting a 360° radial in all direction

[VOR Receiver Check](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap1_section_1.html)

> With the Course Deviation Indicator (CDI) centered, the omni−bear- ing selector should read 0 degrees with the to/from indication showing “from” or the omni−bearing selector should read 180 degrees with the to/from indication showing “to.” **Should the VOR receiver operate an RMI (Radio Magnetic Indicator), it will indicate 180 degrees on any omni−bearing selector (OBS) setting.**

Comment: RMIs don't have an OBS knob though, right?  I thought with a VOR, they would normally just always point to the station in the same manner as an ADF points to an NDB without a manual selection (other than the frequency).  So another way of asking my question is, is the principle of operation of an RMI signal strength modulation(like ADF/NDB) or utilization of the phase difference sent by the VOR.

Comment: @RyanMortensen: I think it's the latter, from the FAA IFR handbook: *"When a needle of the RMI is driven by a VOR receiver, the needle indicates where the aircraft is radially with respect to the VOR station."*

Comment: @ymb1 I just re-read that -- *"Driven by a VOR receiver"*.  So a VOR unit passes information *to* an RMI, and the RMI does not have its own computation equipment?

Comment: @RyanMortensen: Judging by [the RMI's patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3460146), after the VOR receiver input, the RMI still does some work (what exactly I don't know yet). Maybe it's grounds for a new question?